# mod_rewrite and do not put www. if a subdomain already exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

My current .htaccess setting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

If I have the subdomain of `m.mysite.com`, how do I skip adding the www. to the front of it? The rule above sets my URL to `www.m.mysite.com` when I only want `m.mysite.com`.

I put this rule in my .htaccess because I needed `mysite.com` to redirect to `www.mysite.com`.

Thanks for any help.  I will post the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

The following change to line 2 should work. (untested)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)

RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Edit: (explanation) this code adds www only if there's only 1 dot in the host. more than 1 dot would imply the existence of a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteRule .* http(?%1s)://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The main domain name will be hard coded (mentioned only once though) .. but it is the best way.